# Включить MdSched на удалённом компьютере

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, память

Проблема заключается в выборе варианта. Мне нужен второй, но насколько я понимаю, флагов для выбора опций нет, там вообще нет никаких флагов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставить какие - либо сервисы на удалённые машины **крайне нежелательно**, я думал эмулировать нажатия через WinApi, но это плохой вариант. В идеале это окошко с выбором вообще не должно появляться.

Comment: Нет, я хочу запустить эту утилиту и выбрать второй вариант на удалённом компьютере, без необходимости идти к нему. Программа в которой нужен этот функционал пишется на С++, поэтому решил указать. Уберу тег, а то и вправду не в тему

Comment: VBscript не отправляет нажатия клавиш в данную программу. Значит все-таки надо эмулировать нажатия, скорее всего, использованием WinAPI. Отсюда, может понадобиться залить утилиту типа AutoHotKey,AutoIt, nircmd, etc.Если совсем проблема залить утилиту, можно запаковать её в скрипт/батч-файл и запустить. Но это если уже совсем охота поизвращаться.

Comment: Кстати, может протестировать вариант с автоматической загрузкой проверки памяти: **bcdedit /displayorder {memdiag} /addlast** ? Надо будет только добавить автоматическое удаление пункта проверки памяти из меню загрузки по завершению проверки.